# Which section of the GRE-General is more important for a math PhD application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, united-states, gre

I just finished my second attempt at the GRE General after a 2.5 month interval and my Verbal score suffered due to an unscheduled bathroom break and me thinking that that verbal section was for their research purposes and wouldn't be scored. I got 156 in Verbal and 168 in quant and I expect 5 or 5.5 in my essays. For a PhD math admission committee would this score be preferred over my previous score of 161 verbal, 164 quant and 4.5 essay, even though the total is one less?

I already have a 115/120 TOEFL ibt score that could somewhat cover for my poor verbal score here. Also, my GRE subject test in math didn't go too well and while the results are still awaited, I think this would give me another reason to prefer my latest GRE score with higher quant marks.

I've chosen to report both scores to all the universities but some of them ask for one set of unofficial scores listed by the student in the application. So which ones should I choose to mention?

Comment: These differences are so small that it's not really likely to matter.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Am I correct in assuming that Quant scores would be more important in this scenario for phd math than verbal scores? I do fear that 156 verbal might be too low and possibly put me under the cut off for some schools so the one with 161 verbal might be safer to mention in the applications, even though ets will send them both scores later.